# I need to find which ports are being used on a server's IP using python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, port, nmap

I have a server hosting applications on various ports, which get assigned randomly by the server. I want to be able to scan the server's IP, and find which ports I can use to connect to those applications. I have to scan upwards of 50K  (can be anywhere from port 10000 to 60000) ports, so I was looking for an efficient way to do this. I have tried the following:

```
import string
import time
import socket
import threading

from telnetlib import Telnet
from datetime import datetime

import nmap

def main():
    """ Entry point. """
    #known used ports - ['43828','38238','56272']

    # Using nmap - this seems to be the only working code. 
    # But, with a timeout of 0.5 secs, this would take somewhere
    # near 25K secs. Way too long.
    # (Vast majority of ports will be closed, and timeout at a half second. 
    # There will only be a few dozen open ones.)

    t0 = time.time()
    print([testConn('10.159.122.232', x) for x in range(10000, 60000)])
    t1 = time.time()
    print (t1-t0)

    # I found this chunk of code somewhere, using the socket lib, 
    # and attempting multithreading. It never completes (after 30+ min.). 
    r = 10000
    for x in range(1,100):
        t = threading.Thread(target=portscan, kwargs={'host':'10.159.122.232', 'port':r})

        r += 1
        t.start()

    # I ripped this off of the python-nmap website, and it outputs a key error.

    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    nm.scan('10.159.122.232', '38000-39000')
    hosts_list = [(x, nm[x]['status']['state']) for x in nm.all_hosts()]
    for host, status in hosts_list:
        print(host + ' ' + status)
    for port in nm['10.159.122.232']['tcp']:
        thisDict = nm['10.159.122.232']['tcp'][port]
        print ('Port ' + str(port) + ': ' + thisDict['product'] + ', v' + thisDict['version'])

    return 0


def testConn(host, port):
        """ Establish a Telnet connection and perform a login """
        theSession = Telnet()
        try:
            theSession.open(host, port,.1)
            return True
        except:
            return False

def portscan(host, port):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(0.2)

    try:
        con = s.connect((host,port))

        print('Port :',port,"is open.")

        con.close()
    except: 
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Any help?? Most of the threads I am finding are trying to scan open ports on a host FROM the host. I want to scan the host for which ports are being used from a client. That make sense?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in parallel to finish in a reasonable time. That means, for each port, creating a socket, putting it in non-blocking mode, then calling `connect`. When you call `connect` in non-blocking mode, you will get an immediate `BlockingIOError` exception, but the connection attempt is in-progress.

Once you have started all the `connect`s, then you begin polling the file descriptors, waiting to see whether the connection succeeded or not. The hard part here is really just keeping track of the state information for all of the sockets.

Once you find an open port, you can then proceed to `test_conn` to attempt the telnet login.

Things you will need to deal with (these are specific to linux/Unix but there may be similar issues on other platforms):

- There is a limit on the number of open file descriptors at any one time. That limit can usually be raised with `resource.setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, (soft_limit, hard_limit))`.
- By default, each connection request will take around 2 minutes to timeout due to the default number of SYN retries (on linux at least). That may not be a problem since all the connection requests are happening in parallel. But it can be reduced further with `mysock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_SYNCNT, my_syn_retry_cnt)`.
- You'll need to determine when each connection attempt has completed. The best way to do that in parallel is to use the `select` module's `epoll` or `poll` objects. (There are many more examples using `select.select` but the `select` object [on linux, at least] can only poll a maximum of 1024 file descriptors, which would be an issue for your scenario since you will have around 50000.)
- When each connection attempt completes, some will be successful, some not. You can use `mysock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_ERROR)` to determine whether the connection succeeded or not. But if you use `poll`/`epoll`, a flag is returned telling you whether there was an error.

While writing this, I started playing and came up with this quick hack that mostly works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from select import epoll, EPOLLERR
from resource import setrlimit, RLIMIT_NOFILE
from socket import socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_SYNCNT, gaierror

def scan_ip(ip_addr):
    pollobj = epoll()
    fd_socks = [None] * 65540
    open_ports = [None] * 65536
    for n in range(65536):
        sock = socket()
        sock.setblocking(0)
        sock.setsockopt(IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_SYNCNT, 3)
        try:
            sock.connect((ip_addr, n))
            print("??? Port {} connected (immediately)".format(n))
            open_ports[n] = True
            sock.close()
        except BlockingIOError:
            # Store port and socket corresponding to the file descriptor
            fd_socks[sock.fileno()] = (n, sock)
            pollobj.register(sock.fileno())
        except gaierror:
            print("Bad host name")
            return None
        except Exception as exc:
            print("Unexpected failure - {}".format(exc))
            return None

    while any(fd_socks):
        ready_fds = pollobj.poll()
        for fd, event in ready_fds:
            port, sock = fd_socks[fd]
            open_ports[port] = not (event & EPOLLERR)
            pollobj.unregister(fd)
            sock.close()
            fd_socks[fd] = None

    return [n for n, is_open in enumerate(open_ports) if is_open]

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: {} IP-address".format(sys.argv[0]), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    # Raise number-of-open-files-limit
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, (65540, 65540))
    ip_addr = sys.argv[1]
    ports = scan_ip(ip_addr)
    if ports is not None:
        print("{}: {}".format(ip_addr, ", ".join(str(port) for port in ports)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```